# WebView not showing video on Android 2.3.7

Tags: android, android-webview, android-video-player, android-websettings

I try to play dailymotion.com video in Android WebView.

On Android 4.0.1 it runs great when I set android:hardwareAccelerated="true" in the manifest file.

When I use it on Android 2.3.7 the video freezes on the first frame and I can see the following error on logcat:

```
E/Web Console(14426): Uncaught Error: INDEX_SIZE_ERR: DOM Exception 1 at http://static1.dmcdn.net/js/gen/widget/pack/player.js.v43e491a06c202f1e6:1
```

When I play it on Android 4.0.1 built-in browser the video plays inside the browser. When I play it in Android 2.3.7 built-in browser the video seems to be opening an external media player.

This is the code I'm using:

```
mVideoWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
setWebViewSettings(mVideoWebView);
String data_html = "<!DOCTYPE HTML> <html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" 
                    xmlns:og=\"http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/\" 
                    xmlns:fb=\"http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml\">
                    <head></head>
                    <body style=\"margin:0 0 0 0; padding:0 0 0 0;\">
                    <iframe src=\"http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/xu4vre\" 
                            width=\"300\" height=\"162\" frameborder=\"0\">
                    </iframe> </body> </html> ";
mVideoWebView.loadData(data_html, "text/html", null);
public static void setWebViewSettings(WebView webview) {
    WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
    webSettings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(false); // zoom y/n
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true); // true = like desktop
    webSettings.setPluginsEnabled(true);

    //webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    //webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    //webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
}
```

I think that the key for the solution lies in WebChromeClient. If I remove the line `mVideoWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());` the video won't play even on Android 4 and I don't see the error.

Comment: I doubt this is the issue, but your `data_html` String declares a few xml namespaces that aren't used.  Try removing them?  Also the http://static1.dmcdn.net/js/gen/widget/pack/player.js resource has some logic in it to throw / redirect if 'Device not supported', but looking at minimized js makes my head hurt and couldn't work out if Gingerbread would trigger that.

Comment: Try forcing hardware acceleration to false on older phones -- this was a workaround for some graphics-related web view I had before.